# Count appearance of a string in a column access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I made a database and now I am facing some problems.
I am registering all the information about some meetings in a table ( Adunari ):
[image]

I made a query which should show me the name of each member and at how many meetings he was present. I want the 3`rd column to show me the nr of meetings each member was present. I also have a table in which I have the information for each member. I tried using COUNTIF and i tried doing a function with Length of strings, but did not succeed.

[image]

If someone could please explain how can I calculate how many times the string:
Membri.[Nume]+Membri.[Prenume] appears in column Adunari.[Nume Prenume]

Membri - is the table which has the information about members
Adunari - table which has the information about meetings.

Thank you in advice <3. Sorry for this stupid question but I really have no clue, also for a long post.

The tables in design view :

Membri :[image]

Adunari :[image]

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of the design of your tables Membri, Adunari, etc., some sample data for each table and the expected output please?

Comment: The sample data is given in the first image for example we have 2 meetings: 02.12.2015 and 16.12.2015 at each meeting "Rusu Iurie" was present so what I would like to see in the query "Prezente" is a 3`rd column which for each member will show me at how many meetings he was present

Comment: In the first screenshot, is it correct that both Rusu Iurie and Rusu Mihaela attended the meeting on 2.12.2015 and Rusu Iurie also attended meeting on 16.12.2015? What you need is lastname, firstname and count of meeting attended, correct? Also, in your Adunari table, in Nume Prenume column, can you have more than one person? If yes, you probably need normalization and we can talk more about that

Comment: Yes in Adunari table, we can have more that one person this is a list of people separated by newline who attended the meeting at that date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following using either a Count [correlated aggregate subquery](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/aggregating-correlated-sub-queries) or [DCount()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dcount.php) both of which use the [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208897%28v=office.12%29.aspx) operator to match larger text field with concatenation of smaller name fields:

```
SELECT Membri.Nume, Membri.Prenum,

       (Select Count(*) FROM Adunari 
        WHERE [Nume Prenume] 
        LIKE '*' & Membri.Nume & ' ' & Membri.Prenum & '*')  As MatchSubCount,

       DCount("*", "Adunari", "[Nume Prenume] 
              LIKE ""*" & Membri.Nume & " " & Membri.Prenum & "*""") As MatchDCount

FROM Membri
```